# Any drawbacks in using LogBack

Tags: java, logback

I am planning to use LogBack to one of my framework. I found it has many good features.

But is there any drawback in using LogBack?.

Thanks in advance!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really recommend using [log4j2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/). (Note the '2'!).

There is a comparision of different logging frameworks including logback.

Comment: So, Is there any specific reason or advantage. Or Did you find any disadvantage in LogBack which has been overcome by log4j2?

Comment: For details check the log4j2 documentation. One advantage I can remember: log4j2 does not loose log events if changing configuration at runtime.
Besides that log4j2 should probably perform better, by numbers in case of mutlithreading. Furthermore log4j2 supports MessageFormat. Hence you can write for example: LOG.info("User {}", username); and the username is inserted at runtime AFTER having checked your configured log level. This nearly completely (except for autoboxing) removes the need for the "performance optimization" if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) (aims at avoiding unneccessary concatenatio).